# React Native image stream from a server - fps and flickering

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

In my app I want to stream images from a live server and show it in the UI as an ImageBackground component. So that it feels like it is a video, but it is not - just a **fast changing image**, got as **base64** from WebSocket.
The problem is that I'm not sure about the solution I've made, because:

- I'm pretty sure that with higher frame rate it's going to lag the app (now it's 4-5fps, what if 30?)
- When updating an image there's a **flickering effect**, it doesn't feel good (example on video)

Check on video how it currently works: [**video here**](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/840200468188889111/1038811886017319062/Android_Emulator_-_OREO_8.0_API_26_-_Pixel_3a_5554_2022-11-06_14-46-19.mp4)

Code (View):

```
    const liveFrameRef = useRef<Image | null>(null);
    return (
        <ImageBackground fadeDuration={0} style={styles.stream} source={require("../../../../assets/images/camera_preview.jpg")} imageRef={(image) => {
            liveFrameRef.current = image
        }}>
            
        </ImageBackground>
    )
```

Code (Stream in useEffect):

```
        // data - my current image got from a socket as binary
        if (liveFrameRef.current) {
            let bytes = new Uint8Array(data);
            let binary = '';
            let len = bytes.byteLength;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
            }

            const image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + btoa(binary); // b64 encoded JPG

            liveFrameRef.current.setNativeProps({
                src: [{uri: image}],
            });
        }
```

So basically I get the **ref of my Image** and with each frame change the source using `setNativeProps`. That's how I've been doing it in **plain React** in HTML, and worked fine. Here it doesn't. Any better ideas I can workaround this?
Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same problem of flickering in android using react native. Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: please update whenever, you will find solution?

Comment: I managed to solve it using `react-native-fast-image` + the patch from this article https://www.cristiangutu.pro/react-native-fast-image-patch-to-fix-the-image-change-flickering